# How do we translate auxiliaries like “do” or “will” if used without an explicit verb?

Tags: grammaire, anglais

In English, for example, we can say something like “I don't like to exercise but I do” or “I hope he learns Esperanto but I don't think he will”. It isn't necessary to repeat *to exercise* or *to learn*.

How does this work in French? Do we simply use *faire*?

(Also what is the grammatical term for this?)

Comment: Note, this a copy of a similar question on the Esperanto StackExchange: http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/765/how-do-we-translate-to-do-at-the-end-of-a-sentence

Comment: Note that in the English  "do" is not a verb but an auxiliary. *Faire* is a verb meaning "to do" or "to make".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In French you can in most cases use *faire* to replace any other action implied by the context, but you'll also need to refer to the action with a pronoun (*le*).

> Je n'aime pas m'entrainer, mais je *le fais* quand même.
>
> J'aimerais qu'il apprenne l'espéranto, mais je ne crois pas qu'il *le fera*.

Note that you can naturally express tense, but if you also want to express modality (*should*, *could*, etc.), in most cases, you should use a different phrasing.

Comment: qu'est-ce que tu veux dire par "if you want to also express modality...you should use a different phrasing"? Est-ce que "Je n'aime pas m'entrainer, mais je devrais/aurais à/peux/pourrais le faire quand même"ne marche pas ici?

Answer (score 2):

*To do* can simply replaced by the verb *Faire* - The translation

> I don't like to exercise but I do

Is translated to

> Je n'aime pas faire des exercices mais **je le fais** (quand même)

*And*

> I hope he learns Esperanto but I don't think he will

Is translated to

> J'espère qu'il apprend l'Esperanto mais **je ne pense pas qu'il le fera**

In the above example you cann see that you just have to literally translate the verb do with the same tens